# Display elastic beanstalk cron output in events

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have some cron jobs running in my Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance and I'm trying to get the output of the cron to show up in `Events` on the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can write custom output to Beanstalk events. Events are used to show you deployment related activities.